# Plutus Pioneer Cohort 2 Lecture 3

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground

I was going through the lecture on Youtube and this is the one with Vesting example where:

1. wallet 1 gifts 20 ADA to wallet 2 in 2 different slots
2. wallet 1 gifts 10 ADA to wallet 3 in a slot
3. later on, wallets 2 & 3 will grab those gifts after a deadline is passed

So, wallet 1 generates 2 UTXO for wallet 2 to grab & spent. I noticed in the playground that the first UTXO for 10 ADA at script is shown to be spent but the second UTXO is not. But finally, I can see that wallet 2 receives 20 ADA gift in total. Why second UTXO created by wallet 1 to gift wallet 2 is shown unspent although it is spent later on?

[Wallet 1 creating gift UTXO for wallet 2 & it is shown spent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRg33.png)

[Wallet 1 creating gift UTXO for wallet 2 & it is shown unspent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p31NU.png)

[Finally, we can see both UTXO are spent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zuh6k.png)

Comment: Unless I'm truly misunderstanding something, this looks like a bug in the playground.

Comment: I agree. I think this is a bug in a playground, just needed to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Please log a github issue for this https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps
I will make sure it gets followed up on

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I logged a ticket for it in github https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/issues/244

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a bug in the playground.